# How do I reload a React Native page when the time hits midnight?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to build a React Native app and I need to refetch some data to change text on the screen at midnight. My current solution continuously fetches every minute, but is there some way to subscribe to a date change (with a dependency to useEffect maybe?) such that useEffect is only called when the date changes?

Here is my current code

```
  const [timeChanged, setTimeChanged]  = useState(false);
  const [currDate, setCurrDate] = useState<Date>(new Date);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const date = new Date();
      if (date.getDate() !== currDate.getDate()) {
        setTimeChanged(true)
        setCurrDate(date);
      }
    }, 1000); // Check every second
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch some data here...

    setTimeChanged(false);
  }, [timeChanged]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about if instead of adding a `useInterval` you just check the difference between the actual time vs the midnight time and set a `setTimeout` with that timer?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // check actual localtime
    const now = new Date();
    
    // set a timeout for when its midnight
    const midnight = new Date(
      now.getFullYear(),
      now.getMonth(),
      now.getDate() + 1,
      0,
      0,
      0
    );

    // calculate the difference between now and midnight for the timeout
    const timeout = midnight.getTime() - now.getTime();

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(async () => {
      // refresh data
      await someDataRefetcher();
    }, timeout);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, []);
```

This `useEffect` should be probably in your highest in the DOM component such as your `App.tsx` or some other component that never unmounts, therefore that timeout is never cleared while user is using the app.

This what I would do in web, and it probably should work in Native.